# Alljoyn c api read signature

Tags: alljoyn

I have developed some Python bindings for Alljoyn so am using the C api.
I am stuck on reading a signature for some speakers I am controlling.

The signature is quite tricky

"(sxuuuiia(ssssxsssa{ss}a{sv}v))"

I am not sure how to read the array of structs there using the c api.

Anyone have an example ?

The annoying thing is I am only interested in the first string.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I accessed it as "(sxuuuii*)" so not have to deal with the arrays

Comment: Hi Glen, I thing it is better to edit and rephrase the question.